# Where to find the PostgreSQL db file in Cloud9?

Tags: postgresql, cloud9-ide

I recently switched from SQLite to PostgreSQL and am using Cloud9 IDE (Rails). With SQLite there was a file db/development.sqlite that I could open to examine the db contents. Where can I find a similar file now I've switched to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Use a PostgreSQL client like psql or pgAdmin to check your database. You can't just open a file, your database might use thousands (or even millions) of files.

Comment: There is no "DB file" in PostgreSQL. It's a directory full of lots of files managed by a database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

`sudo sudo -u postgres psql`

to access your PostgreSQL server. [Here's some documentation from Cloud9](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/setting-up-postgresql) regarding PostgreSQL.